# Power normalisation of a signal

Tags: power, signal, design, noise

I have two signals, say a and b. Signal a has power of 6 Watt. Signal b is summation of signal a and noise n and has power of 7 Watt. I want to normalize the signal b in a way that its power is equal to the power of signal a. Does anyone have any idea on how to carry out this type of normalization?

Answer (score 1):

Power in electrical and electronic systems is voltage x current. Voltage and current are both signals but power is one signal x another signal. In other words, power doesn't exist as an individual signal.

However, if you had two voltage signals with resistive loads connected to each of them that dissipated the appropriate power, then you could attenuate one voltage and obtain a lower power dissipated in its associated load resistor.